# Meaning of "...Manny, who liked a bit now and again and again."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context: Female student *Manny* locked the door & say this words to her professor before she kissed him.

> Student: I'm not a student anymore.
>
> Professor: I do not think I want to know what that means.
>
> Student: There once was a girl named *Manny* **Who liked a bit now and
>   again, Not now and again, But now and again And again**. Cute?

Comment: I suspect "a bit" refers to sex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A bit" = sex (as already in the comments)

"Not now and again" - "[now and again](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/now-and-again)" normally refers to occasionally, which is "Not" the meaning here

"But now" - now as in "[at the present moment](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/now)"

"and again And again" - meaning having "a bit" multiple times